# Encryption of Data that should be stored in a Database. And understanding the concept of the "key" used,

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, encryption, key

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET and I have to do a project now. It deals with confidential data of a firm's employees so it needs to be encrypted. I am not sure if I will be able to get through with my own encryption algorithm. If I use any existing algorithms, they said that I should find a foolproof way to store the key.

To be honest, I don't really understand the term "key" in encryption. I would like someone to brief about it and help me with how I should move forward with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO:

- as already advised, don't cobble up your "own", use existing algorithms in the framework that have been tested extensively. Whatever weaknesses they may have will (likely) still be better than what you can cobble up on your own.
- understand what needs to be **encrypted** which pretty much means at some point will need to be **decrypted** vs. data that needs to be **hashed** (one-way - e.g. passwords).
- decide if you want this to happen on the application side or perhaps, if resources are available to you like SQL server (to store data), on the database side (discuss this with your DBA). You can do both encryption and hashing in SQL server alone.
- on the application side, you can think about storing keys in your `web.config` and subsequently encrypting that section - just like the option to do so for your db connection strings (encrypting the connection section of web.config). This way even your keys aren't in plain text.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) Can I comment here for more issues??

Comment: The idea is that you ask specific questions, and that you accept the best answer so that others benifit from the q&a. So the best thing is to accept an answer if your problem is solved and you ask new questions when you run into a new prob.

Comment: Okay.. Is there a way where I can ask you to answer to questions I post in the future?

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28cryptography%29

dunno, but maybe start there?

Comment: just google it a bit. you can find tons of information. and if you got specific questions drop 'm on stackoverflow :). also be aware of asking general things, read the FAQ, you can get downvotes for asking for opinions. stackoverflow is mainly intended to solve programming questions. (not trying to talk down on you, just trying to help)

Answer (score 1):

The first rule of cryptography - never use your own algorithm, unless you are a Ph.D. and several other Ph.D's are helping you, even then, use only after public auditing.

What they mean about storing the key is that it shouldn't be exposed anywhere - if an attacker can get the key, they can decrypt all data in the database. Currently, there are no known ways to do this. You can store the key in a file outside the website's root folder - this way either the server itself must be compromised, your app must be compromised (e.g. by making it display the "../../key.txt" file, thus descending below the webroot) or your app must be tricked into encrypting/decrypting the data transparently for the attacker (e.g. by having a bug that allows authentication bypass, thus allowing them to use your app to talk to the database).

For the last part of the question, use @Haxx's answer :)